# HTML table too wide in IE7

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-7

I've got a table that displays fine in Chrome, IE8, and IE9. In IE7, however, the table ends up being much wider than its content (100% of containing element?). How do I make the table only as wide as its content in IE7 and IE6 (and continue to display fine in newer browsers)?

Here's the table:

```
<table class="SisSubDetailTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Date:</td><td>10-16-11</td><td>SOID:</td><td>SUST — Sustaining                                                                                          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Status:</td><td>25 characters' worth of data</td><td>Work Order:</td>
            <td>     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company:</td><td>6K8  — KAPCO</td><td>Sub:</td><td>9999 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Store:</td><td>34 characters' worth of data</td><td>Export Price:</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Class:</td><td>26 characters' worth of data</td><td>Control Ship:</td>
            <td>N</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The following CSS seems to make the cells narrow, but the table as a whole is still much wider than 400px:

```
table.SisSubDetailTable
{
    width: 400px;
}

table.SisSubDetailTable td
{
    border-width: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Actually, the CSS above makes the text wrap as if the cell is actually 100px wide, but the cell border is still quite a bit wider than the text. Strange.

Comment: Another interesting thing: the cell which has no data in it actually doesn't show up in IE7, although I don't think this would make the cells and table so wide. It is an interesting observation, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set its width property in css. Use guess and check to figure out how big you want it.

Comment: I don't know what the width should be ahead of time. Can't I just have the table be as narrow as the data?

Comment: Sorry, there is no shrink-to-fit rule, your going to have to test it, try 300px, then adjust. It should only take a minute.

Comment: Looks like setting the width along with using !important sets the width. Guess I'll just load up a different CSS file for the earlier browsers, but let nature take its course for the newer ones. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not already doing so, set the value in pixels and avoid other units.